# Unix command analogue to DOS command

Tags: unix, batch-file, migration, ksh

I have next command in my batch script

```
dir project\*.java /s /B > temp_file
```

Command gets all `*.java` files from directory and all subdirectories and insert pathes to `temp_file`  .
What is analogue on UNIX for this command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean BASH (Unix can be used with several command line shells, but BASH is definitively the most popular one):

```
find project -name "*.java" >temp_file
```

Comment: _find_ is a binary, _/usr/bin/find_, it has nothing to do with Bash, but otherwise the answer is correct

Comment: I know, but what about the standard output redirection syntax? It's clearly related to the shell you're using, isn't it?

Comment: @H2CO3, in theory, yes, but do know a shell that uses another syntax? different quoting rules could also be an issue.

Comment: @unkulunkulu you're right (that's why I also mentioned that BASH is way more broadly used than its "competitors". Anyway, "In UNIX" is not a very good wording in this case).

Comment: oh, can I write to 'temp_file' full path (/home/.../project/.../file.java) instead of locval path (project/../fila.java) ?

Answer (score 0):

```
find project -iname \*.java > temp_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ls -R  project | grep .\*.java$ > temp_file
```

@unkulunkulu Thanks;)

Comment: this will find "hello.javafoobar" too, you should use "$" at the end